# Python - Taking individual float type outputs from 'for loop' and combining into a single list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

My current outputs are individual floats that are not iterable for my next step: sum() and statistics.mean(). I had attempted at nested list comprehension and when that didn't work, I attempted next at nested loop, but I get the same error - TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable. And by using [ss], each output are listed, but are not combined in a single list.

Any help is appreciated. If you need clarification or have questions, please feel free to ask.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import statistics

frame=[bdrc,bdmp,bdmv,bdsm]     #These are sources selected and then concated for variable, popPrices.
result=pd.concat(frame)
popPrices=result["Price"]

#Grand Mean
xpop=popPrices.mean()           #The mean

for popsq in popPrices:         #An attempt to have each individual sample treated with the grand mean. - success.
   ss=math.pow(popsq - xpop,2)  
   print(ss)                    #This will print floats individually, but need it in a list.
```

Current float output:

```
244107.59945389628
54722.0922075194
6765577.961772737
643320.2371350557
...
...
```

Wanted list output:

```
[244107.59945389628, 54722.0922075194, 6765577.961772737, 643320.2371350557, ..., ...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension

```
ss=[math.pow(popsq - xpop,2) for popsq in popPrices]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import statistics

frame=[bdrc,bdmp,bdmv,bdsm]     #These are sources selected and then concated for variable, popPrices.
result=pd.concat(frame)
popPrices=result["Price"]

#Grand Mean
xpop=popPrices.mean()           #The mean

newList = []

for popsq in popPrices:         #An attempt to have each individual sample treated with the grand mean. - success.
   ss=math.pow(popsq - xpop,2)  
   newList.append(ss)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these items to a list; right now you're just assigning them to a variable. Try this:

```
resultList = []
for popsq in popPrices:treated with the grand mean. - success.
   resultList.append(math.pow(popsq - xpop,2))
print(resultList)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create an empty list and append your results

```
result=[]
for popsq in popPrices:          
   ss=math.pow(popsq - xpop,2)  
   result.append(ss)
```